# How to fix "sources for target ... should be located under ..."?

Tags: c, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package that contains a C target called `mylib`. I'm getting a warning in Xcode that `Source files for target mylib should be located under /path/to/SomeSwiftPackage/Sources/mylib` . The issue is, that's exactly where my source files are located. My `Package.swift` file looks something like this:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SomeSwiftPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SomeSwiftPackage",
            targets: ["SomeSwiftPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "mylib",
            dependencies: []
        ),
        .target(
            name: "SomeSwiftPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "mylib"),
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
SomeSwiftPackage/
  Package.swift
  Sources/
    SomeSwiftPackage/
      SomeSwiftPackage.swift
    mylib/
      include/
        mylib.h
      mylib.c
      helper.h
      helper.c
```

The only file for `mylib` not directly under `/path/to/SomeSwiftPackage/Sources/mylib` is the required header in the include directory. How can I remove this warning?